# How to draw anti-aliased line in cocos2d-x for android games

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

The problem is as what i ask above.In general we can use:

---

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
```

---

But this method is not supported in opengles.So we can't use it for android games.
is there a good way to draw a anti-aliased line for android games in cocos2d-x?Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
try this

CCPoint originPoint=CCPoint(100, 100);
CCPoint destinationPoint=CCPoint(500, 500);

ccDrawLine(originPoint, destinationPoint); // draw line
```

Comment: Thank you.Actually I just did as you said about.But I do want a anti-aliased line.We can use simple method :"glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)" with opengl.But this method is not supported in opengl-es.So what should i do?